# Can I extract a car’s registration number from these images?

Tags: photo-editing

I became the victim of robbers, but a neighbor’s camera filmed their car. I want to know whether it is possible to extract the car’s serial number from these:

Video Link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NuJnCQ0iIpbo7_YTbHvEF1mqvY71xsqh/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: In theory continuous video taken at proper video frame rate could contain hundreds of frames more material from where  high end pattern matching software could decide something useful. Crime investigators and intelligence officials can have it. We have only ordinary photo processing software which cannot find what's common behind a set of images nor can utilize the fact that there's a license plate. None of your included images contain enough data when used separately. Video compression unfortunately removes much data by flattening low contrast areas to zero contrast.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design. What you are showing us appear to be photographs taken from a screen showing a recording. We cannot tell which quality problems arise from your photographing and which are already present in the actual recording. Therefore we can only tell you what can be done with the very images you are showing us. If you want to do this yourself, I strongly recommend that you work with the raw data from your neighbour’s camera.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it i not related to graphic design. This, if anything, would require **forensic image analysis** which is a special field unto itself. In most cases, real-life can not mimic things you see on television shows where things are *miraculously* edited in an image to show the impossible. If you are truly vested in trying to pull data from your images hire an image analysis professional. They are *specifically* trained and experienced in such matters.

Comment: As I said in my answer, your video file is extremely low quality and it doesn't help to post it here, go to the police with the files and let them handle it. Your edit doesn't make the question any better / easier to answer.

Comment: The **best** practice is *always* to go to the police if you have evidence regarding a crime. Graphic Designers aren't crime solvers. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Let's get this out of the way first: we can't help with your image. Now onto the why:

There's not enough data to be recovered from your image. Take this one for example (I reduced to fit the screen, [original size here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a8BH.jpg)):

[image]

1. The number plate is completely white due to the over-exposure of that area (the camera's aperture / exposure was adjusted to capture dark images, so it blows any bright light source).
2. There's quite a lot of noise (both from the jpeg quality and the screen capture)
3. The number plate has a size of approximately 385px * 85px, which would be fine to recover details from if not for 1 and 2 above.

A quick adjustment of the levels shows you that there is not enough detail in the image to recover anything. Also the camera didn't capture enough light information - It could be possible if the original image was shot as a [RAW file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format), since it stores more light information - but even then there would be a chance that the image was just too blurry to start with. That vertical pattern (looks like a TV screen pattern) also obfuscates the details even more.

[image]

In short, only in TV shows like CSI this sort of recovery is possible - because it's fiction, made to move the story forward.

Comment: I would assume that the vertical pattern is due to the images we have being photographs of a TV screen.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft yep that's also what I thought

Comment: Thanks all for reply, I submit here the video link, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NuJnCQ0iIpbo7_YTbHvEF1mqvY71xsqh/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @hillflame you should hire an image analysis professional or take your video to the police, I'm sure they'll be able to handle this.

Comment: Please can someone redirect me to topics that deals my case? Thanks.

Comment: @Hueco all country are not same. our police do not have the means for such an investigation. if that were the case I would be on the first day at the police. if I also had the means I will contact an expert on the subject. To say if I came in this forum is that I need help. It does not just happen to others. I thank all those who helped. Thank you for your attention.